# How to solve $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2 - 8x + 1)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve  $\int\frac{dx}{(x^2 - 8x + 1)}$?

I can't spread it into partial fractions. I can't use u-substitution. And you can't do integration by parts. So, I'm wondering how to do it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: haha. i don't mean that you're not allowed to. it's just that i can't seem to do it with these methods.

Comment: Hint: try completing the square in the denominator.

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion Quoting OP: "I can't spread it into partial fractions."

Comment: @vitamind The word "can't" means "unable."  Are you interpreting it to mean "may not."

Comment: @MarkViola I know this. That's why I asked the OP. See her first comment. Unfortunately I deleted my comment accidentally. (Also it wouldn't make sense if she wants to calculate an integral and is not able to use $u$ sub or integration by parts)

Comment: There are no complex numbers here, $x^2-8x+1=(x-4-\sqrt{15})(x-4+\sqrt{15})$. Use partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use partial fractions.  It isn't necessary that the constants be integers for it to work.
$$\frac{1}{x^2-8x+1} = \frac{1}{(x-4-\sqrt{15})(x-4+\sqrt{15})}$$
or if you prefer to substitute $u = x-4$ first:
$$\frac{1}{u^2-15} = \frac{A}{u-\sqrt{15}} + \frac{B}{u+\sqrt{15}}$$

Comment: thanks. do you get natural log in the answer?

Comment: Yes, as is usual for 1/linear terms getting integrated.

Answer (score 0):

When there are no obvious roots, you can complete the square to arrive either

- to $\displaystyle\int \dfrac {du}{1+u^2}=\arctan(u)$
- or to $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{du}{1-u^2}=\operatorname{argth}(u)$

In the present case $x^2-8x+1=(x-4)^2-15$, so set $u=\dfrac{x-4}{\sqrt{15}}$ and check you get the second form above.

Answer (score 0):

$\int\frac{dx}{x^2-8x+1}=\int\frac{dx}{(x-4)^2-15}$

$\int\frac{dx}{(x-4)^2-15}=\int\frac{dx}{(x-4-\sqrt{15})(x-4+\sqrt{15})}$

$\int\frac{dx}{(x-4-\sqrt{15})(x-4+\sqrt{15})}=\frac12(\int\frac{dx}{x-4-\sqrt{15}}+\int\frac{dx}{x-4+\sqrt{15}})$